# Dropbox Sync API for Android - Unable to start activity

Tags: android, android-studio, dropbox, dropbox-api

I was trying to use the Dropbox Sync API in an Android application (using Android Studio).

I followed the steps at this link:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/start/android

and configured the IDE with these instructions:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/57/using-the-sync-api-with-android-studio

but at Runtime, when I call:

```
DbxAccountManager mDbxAcctMgr = DbxAccountManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
```

(obviously APP_KEY and APP_SECRET are correctly setted) i receive:

```
com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxRuntimeException$BadState: Required Sync API Activity isn't included in application manifest: com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity, com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAuthActivity
```

What have I to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the tutorial, You have to set this inside Your manifest inside the  element:

```
    <activity android:name="com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxAuthActivity" />
  <activity
  android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
 android:launchMode="singleTask" >
<intent-filter>
<data android:scheme="db-APP_KEY" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
 <service
  android:name="com.dropbox.sync.android.DbxSyncService"
  android:enabled="true"
  android:exported="false"
  android:label="Dropbox Sync" />
```

This is to declarate the DropBox Activity, that will be opened for the user sign in.

Comment: Thank you very much, you solved my problem!
Can you please tell me which tutorial are you referring to?

Thanks again!!! :)

Comment: Your welcome...this is in the section "install sdk" at the same tutorial: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/sdks/android

Comment: Ok, I missed the whole "Install SDK" section, thanks!